# Apply color gradient to CAShapeLayer stroke

Tags: swift, gradient, cashapelayer

First sorry, when my english is bad.
I know, my question sounds like a duplicate, but it is different than the others. As it says in the title I want to add a color gradient to the stroke of an CAShapelayer, not in direction of the stroke, but perpendicular to it. For instance i want a gradient from clear to white to clear like this (ignore the grey background):
[image: gradient 1]
[image: gradient 2]
I don't know how to do something like this. I can't use an image or something like this, because I animate the stroke between the straight and the curved line.